# SMTPException happening about 30% of time

Tags: asp.net, .net, smtp, smtpclient

I have asp.net web page, which notifies users by email in certain situations. About 30% of cases however, the email is not sent and SmtpException is being thrown:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: net_io_connectionclosed.

As I have been fighting with this error for a while, I managed to extract SmtpStatusCode which says: "General failure". As a smtp server I am using mandrill with settings:
`<network host="smtp.mandrillapp.com" password="####" port="25" userName="####" enableSsl="false" />`.

Could anyone give me a reason, why this error happens only 30% of times, and not always. I had a look at other questions on stackoverflow, but they concern situation when it does not work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on a residential internet connection,  your ISP will block outgoing email sends by blocking all outbound connections to port 25.Try connecting to a local email server over TCP/IP, or to one on your own internal network.

**Update**

As you are asking for the History, Here is [blog](http://blog.mailgun.com/25-465-587-what-port-should-i-use/) which  i referred to answer your Question

> In 1982, the University of Southern California submitted a proposal to
>   the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF). Request For Comments (RFC)
>   821 was published, establishing port 25 as the default transmission
>   channel for internet email. 30 years later, we still use port 25 as
>   the primary means of transmitting email between two mail servers. A
>   few RFCs have obsoleted the initial SMTP RFC, however, the basis for
>   SMTP remains the same or similar.
>
> In December of 1998, R. Gellens and J. Klensin submitted RFC 2476 in
>   support of adding a new specification for internet email
>   communications. The RFC proposed a split of the traditional message
>   submission and message relay concept. The RFC defined that message
>   submission should occur over port 587 to ensure new policy and
>   security requirements don't interfere with the traditional relay
>   traffic over message relay port 25.

**So Why Port 25 is not working in your case ?**

> It is traditionally blocked, by residential ISPs and Cloud Hosting
>   Providers, to curb the amount of spam that is relayed from compromised
>   computers or servers. Unless you're specifically managing a mail
>   server, you should have no traffic traversing this port on your
>   computer or server.

**Why would 587 will work ?**

> This is the default mail submission port. When a mail client or server
>   is submitting an email to be routed by a proper mail server, it should
>   always use this port.
>
> All Mailgun customers should consider using this port as default,
>   unless you're explicitly blocked by your upstream network or hosting
>   provider. This port, coupled with TLS encryption, will ensure that
>   email is submitted securely and following the guidelines set out by
>   the IETF.

Comment: @Siocki no idea why it happens , did you give a try by changing the port to 587?

Comment: I guess I do not have other choice, but still, I had site, with exactly same settings, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: And my question was again: why does it work that way?

Comment: I marked you answer as correct, but still is it possible that some of mails are marked as spam, that is are blocked, and some aren't? Still the link you sent me was useful.